# On subobjects of a finite-dimensional vector space

Tags: vector-spaces, category-theory, monoidal-categories

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $k$. In a calculation I found myself wondering about this:

Is picking a monomorphism (subobject) $S\to V$ equivalent to picking an element of the dual vector space $V^*$ of $V$?

I can not convince myself on whether this is true or not, so I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem to work particularly well. The closest thing that makes sense to me here is to associate to an element of $V^*$ -- that is, a mapping $V \to k$ -- its kernel, which is indeed a subobject (subspace) of $V$. However, it generally covers only few of the subobjects, namely those with codimension 1. For example, in $\mathbb R^3$, no element of $V^*$ corresponds to the inclusion $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^3: x \mapsto (x,0,0)$. Also, it covers some of the subobjects multiple times; namely, if $f \in V^*$, then any non-zero scalar multiple of $f$ gets associated to the same subspace.

Comment: Well yes, but this is only under the kernel consideration...And it does not say that there does not exist an isomorphism between the sets of objects I mention.

Comment: What would isomorphism mean? $V^*$ is a vector space, while the set of subspaces of $V$ has no such structure. If $k = \mathbb R$ and $V$ is finite-dimensional (for instance) there is certainly a bijection, but this is pretty meaningless.

Comment: Isomorphism of sets of course - bijection. I have not mentioned anything about viewing $V^*$ as a vector space. What about other fields except $\mathbb{R}$? Meaningless, maybe.

Comment: If $k = \mathbb F_2$, and $V = k^2$, then $V^*$ has four elements, but $V$ has five subspaces.

Comment: For what $k$ is this true then? Is it easy to obtain a characterization? I believe it is true for characteristic zero...

Comment: The tags on your post -- category theory and monoidal categories -- suggest that you are looking for something like a *natural* way to associate the two. We are reduced now to something like cardinality arguments, which has very little to do with vector spaces anymore. Intuitively, I am pretty sure that it is false for characteristic zero as well, e.g. $k = \mathbb Q$ and $V = \mathbb Q^\omega$, the space of almost everywhere 0 sequences of rationals. But I don't have a concrete proof of that.

Comment: You are right...